# How do I change the colour of the fold indicator in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have searched through the style configurator on Notepad++ and I can see how to change just about every detail I might want to; except what I'm calling the fold indicator ... when I click on the code in a file, the current fold is highlighted by a fairly bright red line, which is catching my eye all the time. I have searched the internet but I can't find anything. I don't even really know what it's called to search for it.

[image]

Comment: I unfortunately have no idea if this is possible, but could you let me know if this is a predefined color scheme which you can activate/import somehow or did you customize everything by yourself? thanks

Comment: I copied one of the predefined colour schemes and made my own adjustments ... but what worries me is that all the predefined schemes seem to have the same red colour too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following line to the appropriate xml for your theme right after "Fold" in C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Themes:

```
<WidgetStyle name="Fold active" styleID="0" fgColor="FF0000" />;
```

After it's there, it shows up in the style configurator (after either restarting notepad++ or switching themes and switching back to yours) from then on as "Fold Active".